# Combining multiple bodyPattern with logical 'OR' in wiremock

Tags: wiremock

I had a question if its possible to combine multiple body patterns with logical 'OR' operation in wiremock
Currently bodyPatterns is an array that support multiple patterns but they are combined with logical 'AND' by default

for example,

```
{
  "request": {
    "urlPath": "/somePath",
    "method": "POST",
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "matchesJsonPath": "[?(!(@.product.group))]",
        "matchesJsonPath": "[?(!(@.appointment.id))]"
      }
    ]
  },
  
  "response": {
    "status": 400,
    "jsonBody": [
      {
        "code":400,
        "detail":"Missing Required Parameter",
        "field":"product.group, title, id, contact.name, contact.number",
        "message":"The request is missing a required parameter."
      }
    ],
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```

this will match if both product.group and appointment.id is missing from the request.
what configuration change should I do to match this request id either product.group or appointment.id is missing
I just dont want to have a separate config for each validation parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WireMock has an explicit Logical OR operator.](https://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#logical-and-and-or) Simplying adding that `"or"` field between `bodyPatterns` and the `matchesJsonPath` objects should suffice. Logical AND and OR were added in WireMock 2.28.0.

```json
{
  "request": {
    "urlPath": "/somePath",
    "method": "POST",
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "or": [
          {
            "matchesJsonPath": "[?(!(@.product.group))]"
          },
          {
            "matchesJsonPath": "[?(!(@.appointment.id))]"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 400,
    "jsonBody": [
      {
        "code": 400,
        "detail": "Missing Required Parameter",
        "field": "product.group, title, id, contact.name, contact.number",
        "message": "The request is missing a required parameter."
      }
    ],
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```